# Group problem with a diagram

Tags: group-theory, cayley-table

Let the set $M=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and a binary operation $\star$ described in the diagram :

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\star & a & b & c & d \\ \hline
a & a & b & a & b \\
b & b & a & b & a \\
c & a & b & c & d \\
d & b & a & d & c \\
\end{array}$$

Questions given: Is $(M,\star)$ a group? Is $\star$ commutative? Is $c$ the neutral element of $\star$? Is $(\{a,b\},\star)$ a group? Is $(\{a,c\},\star)$ a group?

I obtained that $c$ is the neutral element of the group from the diagram and also that the binary operation is commutative but I am not sure about the other statements.

Comment: I think that should be "Is $(M,\star)$ a group?". I'm trying to work out if it's a monoid...

Comment: Yes it is M.I am sorry for the mistake.

Comment: The multiplication of a group must be a latin square: every elements must occur exactly once in each row and exactly once in each column. This is not sufficient, but it is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a group there is a single element $g$ such that $g^2=g$ (why?). However, your structure has two such elements, $a$ and $c$, and so is *not* a group

For the other two questions: the above also means that $\{a, c\}$ is not a group. On the other hand, $\{a,b\}$ is a group, and proving this is an instructive exercise :-)

---

We can use the table to find the neutral element easily: A neutral element is an element such that the corresponding row *and* column in the table are precisely the outer row and column, respectively (so both are $a,b,c,d$). There can be at most one neutral element. Therefore, $c$ is the neutral element.

We can also see commutativity via the table: this corresponds to the table being symmetric, with the line of symmetry going from top left to bottom right. This is the case here, so the structure is also commutative.

Comment: You mean at least one right?

Comment: @Gregory At least one what? Elements $g$ such that $g^2=g$? No, I mean every group has *precisely* one such element.

Comment: Apologies, I read that as $g^2 = e$.

Comment: @user1729 c is neutral element,right?

Comment: @user1729 * is comutative, right?

Comment: @Vianu02 Yes. The corresponding row *and* column are precisely the outer row and column, respectively (so both are $a,b,c,d$), so this element is the neutral element. Commutativity is seen by noticing that the table is symmetric, with the line of symmetry going from top left to bottom right.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a group, for it does not satisfy the [Latin Square property](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_has_Latin_Square_Property): the first row has two $a$s.

Comment: Alright. But the others statements?It is true what I obtained for them?

Comment: I refer you to user1729's answer, @Vianu02.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a group because at it hasn't the simplification property. Indeed we have :

$$a*a = a*c$$

and "left-simplifying" by $a$, we obtain $a=c$ which is not true.

Remark: in fact, this property is equivalent to the "latin table" property but more usable in the case the table is not explicitly given.

Answer (score 1):

We can also explicitly describe this structure. It turns out it is a monoid. It is the product of the monoid $(\{0,1\}, \max)$ and the group $(\mathbb{Z}_2, +)$.

We have
$$
a = (1, 0) \\
b = (1, 1) \\
c = (0, 0) \\
d = (0, 1)
$$

It is easy to see that $a$ does not have an inverse, that $c$ is the neutral element, that $\{a, b\}$ is a group (with a different neutral element, $a$) and that $\{a, c\}$ is not a group ($a$ has no inverse).

Your structure is furthermore a semiring $(\{0,1\}, \max, \cdot) \times (\mathbb{Z}_2, +, \cdot)$.